# Is there any way we can run composer on Shared Hosting which only provide Cpanel access

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a hosting on Godaddy which only provides access to Cpanel. I have downloaded the FuelPHP code base on the web space but not being able to run command :-

```
php composer.phar update
```

Is there any easy way out ??

Thank you in Advance. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just run it on your local copy, then upload the `vendor` directory. That's where composer stores all the files it grabs, along with the autoloader.

Comment: What we need to do if i have to upgrade the Fuel version??

Comment: In that case you would have to re-upload everything. Fuel is primarily submodule based anyway.